# Control gain on iOS with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I know volume control of an audio tag isn't possible on iOS but I want to bypass that by using Web audio API and modify the value of the gain node. The code is working on desktop but not on iOS, can you see the problem ?

```
    var soundx = document.getElementById("sound");
    var audiocontext =  window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var context = new audiocontext;
    var source1 = context.createMediaElementSource(soundx);
    var gain1 = context.createGain();

        soundx.get(0).play();
        gain1.connect(context.destination);
        source1.connect(gain1);
        gain2.gain.value=0.5;
        gain1.gain.value=0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not connecting source1 to the gain node, and gain2 is undefined (so will throw, and the gain1.gain.value set won't happen.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to delete gain2. But this line doesn't connect the source1 to gain1 ?   `source1.connect(gain1);`